# Event binding issue

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling

[I would like to make this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drgwk.png)

```
class FitFunctions:
    def find_baseline(self):
        self.fit_box.butt5.grid(row=0, column=10, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="n")
        self.fit_box.info.grid(row=0, column=8, padx=5, pady=10)
        print("Find Baseline.")
        self.fit_box.fit_canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.add_point)
    def add_point(self, event):
        print("add point event is on air")
```

and the widget:

```
class FittingBox(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, uv_tab, uv_f):
        # (initialized things)
        self.butt3 = ttk.Button(self.lablfrm3, text="make points", command=self.fit_f.find_baseline)
```

the result:

```
Find Baseline.    # only this message shows.
add point event is on air    # if the binding is okay, it should be shown.
```

There doesn't seem to be any particular error message,
but I don't know why the event is not bound.

Comment: Hmm...self comment,...-_-;;;
This issue has cleared by adding status